What is this mysterious firmware upgrade popup?
I've been getting this popup for the last few days now.

The popup is from an "Unknown App".
Does anyone know what this is from? Not sure what other information I can provide, but the operating system is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Is this malware of some kind?

Wait for the next time it shows up and then, without closing the window, go to a terminal and run ps aux > with.window. Then close it, go back to the terminal and run ps aux > no.window. Next, run diff <(sort with.window) <(no.window) and post the output here. That will show us any processes that were running while the window was open and went away when it was closed.

@terdon , thank you. I'll try this, and update this post with the diff results (if any).

A couple of clarifications, Dunois: when I said "close it" I mean "close the popup window", not the terminal (sorry, on re-reading, I realized that wasn't clear). Also, the command should be diff <(sort with.window) <(sort no.window), both files need to be sorted. Good luck!

Do fwupmgr or fwuptool mention this tool?

@terdon the pop-up showed up again today, but I couldn't catch it, as it just disappeared on its own before I could even open the command line to run ps. I'll keep trying.

@terdon I think I tracked down the source of this popup using your suggestion. Looks like it is this binary /snap/firmware-updater/127/bin/firmware-notifier. When I executed it manually, it produced the popup in the OP again. Any ideas where this is from? /snap/firmware-updater/127/meta/snap.yaml has some information but I can't find who the source is; I'm guessing it's this one https://snapcraft.io/install/firmware-updater/ubuntu. Is this really from Canonical?
